UPI Linking Gpay and paytam error when try to pay amount
i am trying to pay amount through anchr tag or save value in qr code own qr code but facing issue
using deeplink UPI payment
same issue facing paytm work only samething phone pe
 Gpay 
this link i also save into QR Code but not working
upi://pay?appid=inb_admin&tr=IND89e6f9730dc34&mc=&pa=60491657854@mahb&pn=Jomar TRADERS'
enter image description here
trying deeplinking upi payment faild to gpay and paytm
